# How to disabled direction for routing in Spatialite Dijkstra-algorithm ?

Tags: routes, dijkstra, spatialite

i'm using Spatialite in my application to provide an offline routing service from OSM data.

This works perfectly, specially for car drivers because it takes care of the way direction.

But, how to provide a route by the shortest path, with no care about direction ?

I couldn't see any params to set in the query that seems to be stricly : 
"select * from roads_net where NodeFrom = 27173 and NodeTo = 26984"

I tried to build spatialite_network with --unidirectional or --bidirectional but that gives the same results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A Spatialite `VirtualNetwork` can be either *unidirectional* or *bidirectional*, you cannot change shortest path result at runtime (which is quite limiting). Try rebuilding your network using the [GUI tool](https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.0/binaries.html).